# angular flexlayout layoutgap rtl direction

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, right-to-left, angular-flex-layout

I wrote Angular application and use angular material with **flexLayout**.

I have a problem with style `direction:rtl`

The **fxLayoutGap** appear as right margin before each element ***except for the last***.

See the exmple here:
[stackblitz angular material flex layout rtl gap](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed-jcoewf)

(I successed to resolve the issue with empty div after the last element but is so ugly... See [stackblitz angular material flex layout rtl gap with empty div](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed-qgqumy?file=app/app.component.ts))

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

i think it's problem of `fxLayoutGap` when the direction is reverse. you can add:

```css
.mat-form-field:last-child{
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

or you can remove the `fxLayoutGap` and add `25px` right margin to child items:

```css
.mat-form-field{
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

to global `src/styles.css` file.

[forked demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed-nksgsm).

Comment: Thank you, I think of the solution with the last-child, but its be true only for specific gap. I want infrustructre solution to prevent handling within every component.

Comment: @StackOverflow check this [issu](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/450). From the docs: fxLayoutGap does not respond to reveresed flow directions. but i think it's fixed in newer versions or will be fixed.